# Normal distribution interval

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am trying to find $c$ so that $P(|X - 5| < c) = .95$ with $\mu = 5, \sigma^2 = 4$.

I came up with: $P( \frac{-c}{2} < Z < \frac{c}{2}) = .95$

Attempting to solve for $c$, the $z$-score for $c$ is $c = 1.65$, but I know this is not the correct answer. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want probability $0.025$ in the right tail, same in the left tail. Look for $1-0.025=0.975$ in the **body** of the table. This corresponds (approximately) to $1.96$. So you want $c/2\approx 1.96$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks for your input. Why am I looking for .025 in the right tail?

Comment: @Doug Ramsey:$P( \frac{-c}{2} < Z < \frac{c}{2}) = 2P( 0 < Z < \frac{c}{2})=.95$ then$$P( 0 < Z < \frac{c}{2})=\frac{.95}{2}$$ you  find value of $\frac{c}{2}$ Standard normal table

Comment: In the main part, between the two tails, you want probability (area) $0.95$. So the combined area of the two tails is $0.05$, meaning $0.025$ to each.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I completely follow the logic. But I still don't understand *why* I want the probability of 1 - 0.025.

Comment: You want to locate the appropriate $c/2$. Tables tell you $\Pr(Z \le z)$, usually only for $z$ between $0$ and $3.4$. We want right tail of $0.025$, but you will not find that information directly in the table, since it gives $\Pr(Z\le z)$, not $\Pr(Z\gt z)$. But the fix is easy: $2.5\%$ to the right of  $z$ is the same event as $97.5\%$ to the left of $z$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Again I follow that logic. I just don't understand why we want 2.5% in the tail. What about the problem draws the conclusion that we want the probability of 2.5%? I thought we wanted probability of 95%? What does c represent in this?

Comment: You need to have a picture of the standard normal in your head, or in front of you. We want the number $d$, which is $c/2$, be such that $\Pr(-d\le Z\le d)=0.95$. So the part between $-d$ and $d$ should have area (probability) $0.95$. That means that the part beyond $d$, and the part before $-d$, should have combined area $0.05$. By symmetry, the part after $d$ has area $0.025$, so the part **before** $d$ has area $0.975$. Look this up in the table. You get $d=1.96$. (Continued)

Comment: Another way: Between $-d$ and $d$ is $0.95$. So by symmetry the part between $0$ and $d$ has area half of that, which is $0.475$. So the area from $-\infty$ to $d$ is $0.5+0.475=0.975$. Look for $0.975$ in the body of the normal table to find $d$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thank you for your comments! This is exactly the answer I was looking for :). If  you would like to take your comments and create an answer to the question, I'll be happy to up-vote and accept.